# Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on mac

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a basic app using react native. When I run the app using `react-native run-android`, the app runs successfully on a connected device.

Now I want to share the apk file with the client. For that I have created the apk following the steps mentioned on:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.51/signed-apk-android.html

When I install the app using the generated apk, the app installs successfully, but gives the following error when the app is opened the first time.

[image]

After that whenever I open the app, I get a blank screen.

Comment: You are not building it correctly, most probably. there are certain commands to get both debug apk and release apk.

Comment: Thanks for reply @SenthilBalaji...
I used "gradlew assembleRelease" as well as "gradlew assembleDebug", but the result was same, unfortunately.

Comment: did u run this command before running `gradlew assembleDebug`? this:`react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
`

Comment: yes...I used this command also...no success...